# Cannot declare pointer to non unmanaged type int* C#

Tags: c#, pointers, unmanaged, fixed, managed

```
  unsafe static void Main(string[] args)
  {
      int i=6;
      int* j = &i; //Allowed
      int* k = j; //Allowed
      fixed(int* q = &i) //Allowed
      {
      }
      fixed(int* q = j) //Cannot declare pointer to non unmanaged type int* 
      {
      }
   }
```

What I am doing with the 2nd fixed block is pretty much the same as what I am doing with the first fixed block.
I am assigning the address of a variable i, to a pointer q. Direct address assignment is permitted, while taking the address in another pointer and using that pointer in the assignment fails. The same steps however worked, outside of the fixed context.. What's going on?!

Comment: Are you sure that's the error text? Please cut and paste the exact text.

Comment: The first fixed block isn't valid for me... "You cannot use the fixed statement to take the address of an already fixed expression". Please post your exact code.

Answer (score 0):

What version of C# are you using? The first `fixed` statement doesn't compile for me either (`You cannot use the fixed statement to take the address of an already fixed expression`).

Fixing an unmanaged pointer doesn't make sense. It's already fixed, it can't ever be touched by the GC.

This changes when you make `i` a member field of a class, for example. Suddenly, it's no longer scoped to the method, and *can* be moved by the GC (along with its countaining object). In that case, you *have* to use the `fixed` statement.

The compiler will not allow you to take a pointer to an unfixed managed variable, and it will not allow you to fix an unmanaged or fixed variable.

The same way, if you take a pointer to the beginning of an array, eg. make `int[] i` and take `&i[0]`, it again needs to be fixed, because it's no longer guaranteed to be locally scoped. If you do need a locally scoped unmanaged array, you can use the `stackalloc` keyword, but again, that basically means you're cutting yourself from the relative safety of managed .NET.

Answer (score 0):

[The `fixed` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f58wzh21.aspx) is used to *pin* a managed variable, so that the garbage collector won't move it.

In normal operation, the garbage collector is free to move objects around. This would be a problem for pointers because if the garbage collector moved an object you had a pointer to, the pointer would no longer be valid. `fixed` provides a solution to this by letting you *pin* the variable, telling the garbage collector that pointers to the object may exist and that it must not move them for the duration of the code block.

> The C# compiler only lets you assign a pointer to a managed variable in a fixed statement.

Variables allocated on the stack (value types) are not subject to the garbage collector and will not move in memory, so `fixed` is both unnecessary and incorrect for such variables. That's why your second (and indeed your first) `fixed` statement produces an error.